# WebSphere MQ setjmsenv / setjmsenv64 scripts missing

Tags: ibm-mq

I have WebSphere MQ Client v7.1 on a 64-bit Linux box. I see setmqenv and setmqinst scripts on /opt/mqm/bin directory. I do not see setjmsenv64 or setjmsenv there. What else do I need to install to get these. I want to include this in the .profile to set the environment paths and then to set the classpaths. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in `/opt/mqm/java/bin` instead.  I just downloaded and installed the current version from [SupportPac MQC71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71) onto a Linux x64 VM and verified it has the required files.

```
SLESS11X64:/tmp/wmq # ll
total 351112
-r--r--r--  1  226 12201       261 2011-10-14 16:36 copyright
-rwxr-xr-x  1  226 12201      4590 2011-10-14 16:36 crtmqpkg
drwxr-sr-x  4  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:36 lap
drwxr-sr-x  2  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:36 licenses
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  216757299 2012-03-29 14:11 mqc71_7.1.0.0_linuxx86-64.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1  226 12201      5228 2011-10-14 16:36 mqlicense.sh
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201   4144935 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesClient-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201  22345729 2011-10-14 16:36 MQSeriesGSKit-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201  23640155 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesJava-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201  70922394 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesJRE-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201    293337 2011-10-14 16:36 MQSeriesMan-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201  18887546 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesRuntime-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201    831749 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesSamples-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201    244406 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesSDK-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201   1015568 2011-10-14 16:36 MQSeriesXRClients-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
drwxr-sr-x  3  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:36 PreReqs
drwxr-sr-x 18  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:42 READMEs
drwxr-sr-x  2  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:36 repackage
SLESS11X64:/tmp/wmq # ./mqlicense.sh -accept

Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 

 5724-H72 

 (C) Copyright IBM Corporation 1994, 2011 All rights reserved.

US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure
restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.



Agreement accepted:  Proceed with install.

SLESS11X64:/tmp/wmq # ll
total 351112
-r--r--r--  1  226 12201       261 2011-10-14 16:36 copyright
-rwxr-xr-x  1  226 12201      4590 2011-10-14 16:36 crtmqpkg
drwxr-sr-x  4  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:36 lap
drwxr-sr-x  2  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:36 licenses
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  216757299 2012-03-29 14:11 mqc71_7.1.0.0_linuxx86-64.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1  226 12201      5228 2011-10-14 16:36 mqlicense.sh
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201   4144935 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesClient-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201  22345729 2011-10-14 16:36 MQSeriesGSKit-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201  23640155 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesJava-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201  70922394 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesJRE-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201    293337 2011-10-14 16:36 MQSeriesMan-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201  18887546 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesRuntime-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201    831749 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesSamples-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201    244406 2011-10-14 16:35 MQSeriesSDK-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r--  1  226 12201   1015568 2011-10-14 16:36 MQSeriesXRClients-7.1.0-0.x86_64.rpm
drwxr-sr-x  3  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:36 PreReqs
drwxr-sr-x 18  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:42 READMEs
drwxr-sr-x  2  226 12201      4096 2011-10-14 16:36 repackage
SLESS11X64:/tmp/wmq # rpm -ivh *rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
Creating group mqm
Creating user mqm
   1:MQSeriesRuntime        ########################################### [ 11%]
   2:MQSeriesJRE            ########################################### [ 22%]
   3:MQSeriesClient         ########################################### [ 33%]
   4:MQSeriesGSKit          ########################################### [ 44%]
   5:MQSeriesJava           ########################################### [ 56%]
   6:MQSeriesMan            ########################################### [ 67%]
   7:MQSeriesSamples        ########################################### [ 78%]
   8:MQSeriesSDK            ########################################### [ 89%]
   9:MQSeriesXRClients      ########################################### [100%]

SLESS11X64:/opt/mqm/java # ll /opt/mqm/java/bin
total 72
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm   750 2011-10-14 16:32 Cleanup
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm   315 2011-10-14 16:32 formatLog
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm   804 2011-10-14 16:32 IVTRun
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm  1045 2011-10-14 16:32 IVTSetup
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm  1478 2011-10-14 16:32 IVTTidy
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm   952 2011-10-14 16:32 JMSAdmin
-r--r--r-- 1 mqm mqm  3375 2011-10-14 16:32 JMSAdmin.config
-r--r--r-- 1 mqm mqm 15354 2011-10-14 16:32 jms.config
-r--r--r-- 1 mqm mqm  7389 2011-10-14 16:32 MQJMS_PSQ.mqsc
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm   827 2011-10-14 16:32 PSIVTRun
-r--r--r-- 1 mqm mqm   236 2011-10-14 16:32 PSReportDump.class
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm  1041 2011-10-14 16:32 runjms
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm  1356 2011-10-14 16:32 setjmsenv
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mqm mqm  1372 2011-10-14 16:32 setjmsenv64
SLESS11X64:/opt/mqm/java #
```

Comment: I thought it might have been a packaging error so I had to see for myself.  :-)